# ¿Cuál es el método para conseguir los datos introducidos en un CUSTOM_DIALOG (FileChooser) en Java?

Tags: java, jfilechooser

He buscado exhaustivamente el método para conseguir los datos que el usuario introduce como "Nombre del archivo" cuando se muestra un jFileChooser, ¿Hay alguna manera de sacar el texto como String como si fuese un jTextField?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En la documentación hay un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo, usando el método `getSelectedFile()` seguido de `getName())`:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
    "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
        chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
}
```

Dejo el [enlace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).

Comment: He intentado usar esos dos métodos, sin embargo, solo funcionan cuando el archivo es seleccionado, quisiera saber si es posible conseguir aquel "Nombre" sin tener que seleccionar nada, simplemente escribir y sacar aquel texto escrito sin necesidad de que exista dicho archivo. :(

Comment: ¿Para qué necesitas hacer eso? El archivo no tiene por qué existir si, por ejemplo, estás guardando.

Comment: Tengo un File Chooser ya visible dentro de una ventana jFrame, bien podría mostrar uno para cada botón de abrir o guardar, sin embargo, deseaba dejar solo un File Chooser para ambos casos.